# Zurb foundation tabbing through form fields and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

Using Zurb Foundation 5, I have a form

```
    <form>
        <h2>Add or edit</h2>
            <label for="n_shortname">Name in figure:</label>
            <input type="text" id="n_shortname"/><br>
            <label for="n_phosphorylated">P? (Phosphorylated?)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="n_phosphorylated"><br>
        <a class="button" id="save-button">Save</a>
    </form>
```

When filling out the form, I can use the tab key to move through the inputs, but when I get to the last item (the checkbox) and hit tab, instead of moving focus to the button (so I can "save" by hitting the enter key) the focus goes to the top of the page.  How do I make the focus go to the button next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I changed it to:

```
    <form>
        <h2>Add or edit</h2>
        <label for="n_shortname">Name in figure:</label>
        <input type="text" id="n_shortname"/><br>
        <label for="n_phosphorylated">P? (Phosphorylated?)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="n_phosphorylated"><br>
        <input type="button" class="button" id="save-button" value="Save"></input>
    </form>
```

Comment: So it was skipping the save button because it did not have a defined type?

Comment: I believe it was skipping because of the "a" element rather than "input" element.  If I remove the `type="button"` part it still tabs to the button like I want it to (though it doesn't format the way I want).

Comment: Holy crap, I didnt even notice that. Duh!